# How can I properly generate xml elements using intellisense and xml schemas in vb.net?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Using intellisense in VB.NET, how can I properly generate xml elements? 
Whenever I try to add values to child elements they are ignored.

Consider this code:

```
Dim XML As XElement = <Customer/>
With XML
    .SetAttributeValue("ID", 1)
    .<CustomerNumber>.Value = "D234"
    .<Name>.Value = "SomeName"
End With
Debug.WriteLine(XML.ToString)
```

This will output:

```
<Customer xmlns="http://Customer" ID="1" />
```

In other words the child elements "CustomerNumber" and "Name" are ignored.

How can I properly add the child elements using this intellisense approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not ignored - they don't exist.

```
Dim XML As XElement = <Customer>
                        <CustomerNumber/>
                        <Name/>
                      </Customer>
With XML
  .SetAttributeValue("ID", 1)
  .<CustomerNumber>.Value = "D234"
  .<Name>.Value = "SomeName"
End With
Debug.Write(XML.ToString)
```

Comment: Ok, I see, I hoped that they would be created automatically when used. Because I don't get any intellisense help in the declaration. That is, I basically need to remember that "CustomerNumber" and "Name" are valid child elements in the "Customer" element. Is there anyway to obtain intellisense in the declaration?

Comment: Not that I know of. I wish it did too. I think there is just no metadata for intellisense to pick up from.